# Класс SendKeys в C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет, скажите вот я почитал MSDN про этот класс, но там не сказали как в этом классе делать сочетания клавиш? К примеру Ctrl + A.. Там только про одну клавишу.

Comment: О, отличный вопрос, сам ищу на него ответ.

Answer (score 1):

[SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

> Чтобы указать клавиши, которым соответствуют неотображаемые символы, например клавишу ВВОД или TAB, или клавишу, представляющую действие (а не символ), используйте коды, приведенные в следующей таблице.
>
> `...
> ВВОД    {ENTER}
> ESC     {ESC}
> ...`
>
> Чтобы представить несколько символов, каждый дополнительный символ нужно добавлять к предыдущему. Так, для представления букв A, B и C следует в качестве параметра указать "ABC".
>
> Чтобы указать, что при нажатых клавишах SHIFT, CTRL или ALT нажимаются несколько других клавиш, коды последних следует заключить в скобки. Например, чтобы указать, что клавиши E и C нажимаются, пока клавиша SHIFT удерживается нажатой, используйте строку "+(EC)".

Comment: Да это я знаю, я не знаю как сделать сочетание клавиш... делал так:

    SendSeys.Send({^A});

Но не работает(

А можно пример любого сочетания:

Answer (score 1):

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^{a}"); //меня спасла строчная буква
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SendSeys.Send("^A");
```

[Смотреть в разделе "Заметки"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Comment: Да я читал, и там ошибка:

 Keyword "^A" is not valid.

Comment: Хм... попробуйте так:
   SendKeys.SendWait("^A");
У меня работает (WPF, VS 2010)